# How do I stop jQuery from injecting junk attributes into my HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML unordered list in a Content Editor web part that I'm formatting as tabs where each has an onclick event to show/hide some other data. The issue is that I'm getting all these weirdo attributes injected into my LI elements and it's bloating my page.

Here's the initial HTML:

```
<ul id="HPTabs">
   <li id="HP-CompNews">
      <div class="Active">Company News</div>
   </li>
   <li id="HP-MyLoc">
      <div>My Location</div>
   </li>
   <li id="HP-MyInfo">
      <div>My Information</div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Here's my click event:

```
$('ul #HPTabs li div').click(function () {
   $('ul #HPTabs').find(".Active").removeClass('Active');
   $(this).addClass('Active');
   $('#HP-CompNews, #HP-MyLoc, #HP-MyInfo').css('display', 'none');
   $('#'+$(this).parent().attr('id').split('-')[1]).css('display', 'block');
});
```

The functionality works as intended except that for every click, another jquery(GUID?)="someNumber" attribute gets injected into my HTML. Here's an example of what it looks like after a few clicks:

```
<ul id="HPTabs">
   <li id="HP-CompNews">
      <div class="Active" jquery110204516100992192893="16" jquery1102032202719870924345="16" jquery110201957534008842723="16" jquery110206010765075112563="16" jquery110205030024967078637="16" jquery11020240918390025753="16" jquery110205795853442488423="16" jquery110207744044316576384="15" jquery110206115635669787789="15" jquery110209485645959143213="15" jquery1102037456364818752646="15" jquery110201352150105905291="15" jquery110209849012308610433="15" jquery110204805339193009697="15" jquery110207504123057924319="15" jquery1102049844052243903514="15" jquery110209780298183681414="15" jquery110202694160068175796="15" jquery11020018363243469401324="15" jquery1102011301930135993976="15" jquery1102026479443747328696="15" jquery1102030561950264041976="15" jquery110202945977674906085="15" jquery110207990703522867846="15" jquery1102035656433625163564="15" jquery110200921925300649431="16" jquery11020041262761778884216="16" jquery110200075315197566104275="16" jquery1102029544368951496863="16" jquery1102044976213483513166="15" jquery1102024529203354116913="15" jquery110205500073059982571="15" jquery110204459848878633349="15" jquery110204810727017335449="15" jquery110207130104700713545="15" jquery110204107102120462112="15" jquery110208062580827974011="15" jquery110207526860699211768="15" jquery110203082284355632704="15" jquery1102043527519695676786="15">Company News</div>
   </li>
   <li id="HP-MyLoc">
      <div jquery110204516100992192893="18" jquery1102032202719870924345="18" jquery110201957534008842723="18" jquery110206010765075112563="18" jquery110205030024967078637="18" jquery11020240918390025753="18" jquery110205795853442488423="18" jquery110207744044316576384="17" jquery110206115635669787789="17" jquery110209485645959143213="17" jquery1102037456364818752646="17" jquery110201352150105905291="17" jquery110209849012308610433="17" jquery110204805339193009697="17" jquery110207504123057924319="17" jquery1102049844052243903514="17" jquery110209780298183681414="17" jquery110202694160068175796="17" jquery11020018363243469401324="17" jquery1102011301930135993976="17" jquery1102026479443747328696="17" jquery1102030561950264041976="17" jquery110202945977674906085="17" jquery110207990703522867846="17" jquery1102035656433625163564="17" jquery110200921925300649431="18" jquery11020041262761778884216="18" jquery110200075315197566104275="18" jquery1102029544368951496863="18" jquery1102044976213483513166="17" jquery1102024529203354116913="17" jquery110205500073059982571="17" jquery110204459848878633349="17" jquery110204810727017335449="17" jquery110207130104700713545="17" jquery110204107102120462112="17" jquery110208062580827974011="17" jquery110207526860699211768="17" jquery110203082284355632704="17" jquery1102043527519695676786="17">My Location</div>
   </li>
   <li id="HP-MyInfo">
      <div jquery110204516100992192893="19" jquery1102032202719870924345="19" jquery110201957534008842723="19" jquery110206010765075112563="19" jquery110205030024967078637="19" jquery11020240918390025753="19" jquery110205795853442488423="19" jquery110207744044316576384="18" jquery110206115635669787789="18" jquery110209485645959143213="18" jquery1102037456364818752646="18" jquery110201352150105905291="18" jquery110209849012308610433="18" jquery110204805339193009697="18" jquery110207504123057924319="18" jquery1102049844052243903514="18" jquery110209780298183681414="18" jquery110202694160068175796="18" jquery11020018363243469401324="18" jquery1102011301930135993976="18" jquery1102026479443747328696="18" jquery1102030561950264041976="18" jquery110202945977674906085="18" jquery110207990703522867846="18" jquery1102035656433625163564="18" jquery110200921925300649431="19" jquery11020041262761778884216="19" jquery110200075315197566104275="19" jquery1102029544368951496863="19" jquery1102044976213483513166="18" jquery1102024529203354116913="18" jquery110205500073059982571="18" jquery110204459848878633349="18" jquery110204810727017335449="18" jquery110207130104700713545="18" jquery110204107102120462112="18" jquery110208062580827974011="18" jquery110207526860699211768="18" jquery110203082284355632704="18" jquery1102043527519695676786="18">My Info</div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Is this barrage of garbage attributes SharePoint's way of being helpful? Or is it a jQuery syntax issue on my click event?  I wouldn't have a problem with a single attribute getting injected if it needs to happen but a new attribute with each click? C'mon..

This is on SP Server 2013 - Standard using jquery 1.10.2

Comment: The "Off topic" point trolls are suggesting I move this thread to stack overflow... But since SharePoint is a platform and this question relates to programming the DOM on the platform, it's valid to keep it here.

Comment: I do not agree in this case, this question and the answer would be exactly the same if you added the same code elsewhere. This is a built-in jQuery behavior and not SharePoint specific.

Comment: But as all ways, it is up to the community to decide. Since you have edited your post, a poll for reopening has started and hence given the community members with enough reputation the possibility to vote to reopen or keep closed :)

Comment: Given SharePoint's previous behavior of injecting garbage attributes into HTML in SharePoint Designer, similarities can be made between the Designer HTML injection bugs and this issue.

Comment: You should actually try to put this HTML and JS outside SharePoint to confirm that its JQuery and not SharePoint :)

Answer (score 3):

Those are the [jQuery expando](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922441/what-is-the-meaning-of-jquery-random-attributes-in-html-expando-attribute) added attributes.  As I understand, jQuery uses these for object caching and avoiding circular references.  Also, if you call .html() on a jQuery object, it shouldn't include the expando properties.

They shouldn't impact performance in a negative way.

Comment: Thanks Tyshock. So I'm not understanding this whole idea that if an element has one million of these attributes on a single DOM element that it doesn't affect performance.  I mean the expando integers don't change once they are created so they have to use memory, right?

Comment: I did what you suggested and called .html on the element with these 'expandos' and it returned the item with the expando's included... so they are in the DOM